# Add an image to a navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I want to change the **image**, the title and the color of a backButton in the navigationBar. Here the code:

```
UIButton* backButton = (UIButton *) [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButtonTopBar.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"TopBar.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

but I have some problems:

1. the black color not point
2. the back image not working

So someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this page: [foobarpig.com](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/uinavigationbar-with-solid-color-or-image-background.html) **EDIT:**
Apparently doesn't work on iOS 5.0

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton * backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];

[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:BACK_BUTTON_IMAGE_NORMAL] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:BACK_BUTTON_PRESSED] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    UIView * backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(BACK_BUTTON_FRAME)];

    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    

    [backButtonView addSubview:backButton];

    UIBarButtonItem * backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButtonView];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;

[backButtonView release];

[backBarButton release];
```

Comment: What does it mean "101"? Make attention to memory leaks. Thank you.

Comment: 101 is the button type of BackButton.The left end will be finished arrow as our normal backbuttons.

Answer (score 0):

What does this line of code mean?

```
UIButton* backButton = (UIButton *) [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButtonTopBar.png"]];
```

If you need to create a button, you have to do the following.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

and then set to it the background image.

But the way I prefer is to create a category extension for `UIBarButtonItem` like the following

```
//UIBarButtonItem+YourPreferredName.h    
+ (UIBarButtonItem*)barItemWithImage:(UIImage*)image title:(NSString*)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

//UIBarButtonItem+YourPreferredName.m    
+ (UIBarButtonItem*)barItemWithImage:(UIImage*)image title:(NSString*)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // additional customizations here...

    UIBarButtonItem* barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    return [barButtonItem autorelease];    
}
```

If you import `UIBarButtonItem+YourPreferredName.h` where you need it, then you can use as the following:

```
UIBarButtonItem* backBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem barItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YoutImageName"] title:@"YourTitle" target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
```

where `goBack` could be the following:

```
- (void)goBack:(id)sender
{
   // do stuff here
}
```

Hope it helps.